# Numbers on MIDI Tracks in Garageband

Tags: garageband, midi

I'm trying to use a SoundFont with a midi track but for some reason I see a number surrounded by a box at the start of the midi track.

[image]

Is there any way to change the value of this number in Garageband, or do I have to use something else?

Comment: Wow, this is on Google.